# A question on the Riemann zeta function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, l-functions

**Question:** Consider a $L$-shaped path $L_\epsilon:\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\to \frac{1}{2}+\epsilon+i\ (H+\epsilon)\to \frac{1}{2}+i\ (H+\epsilon)$ where $H>0$ is fixed and $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small. If the Riemann zeta function, **$\zeta(s)$ is non zero on $L_\epsilon$** then prove that $$\int_{L_\epsilon} \frac{d}{ds}\log[(s-1)\zeta(s)]\ ds = \log\left[\left(-\frac{1}{2}+i(H+\epsilon)\right)\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i(H+\epsilon)\right)\right]-\log\left(\left(\epsilon-\frac{1}{2}\right)\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)\right)$$
**My Try:** Since the function $f(s)=(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is entire and  $f(s)$ has no zeros on $L_\epsilon$ so we can for each point $s'\in L_\epsilon$ find a small neighbourhood $U(s')$ so that $f(s)\neq 0$ $\forall s\in U(s')$. Hence we can find an open set $U=\bigcup\limits_{s'\in L_\epsilon} U(s') $, so that $L_\epsilon\subset U$ and $f(s)\neq 0$ for every $s\in U$.

But Fundamental Theorem of Calculus would not work due to singularities involved and the logarithm of the zeta function must be defined carefully.

Comment: Why the downvote? Because it is a research level question?

Comment: No, probably because you offer no motivation, no context, no work of your own and sort of just demand an answer. Please read this short page: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

(I didn't vote on your question either way btw)

Comment: @Arkady I have added my work. Please see and answer

Comment: (+1) Thank you for taking the feedback and improving your question.
You found an open simply connected region $U$ on which $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is non-zero, therefore you can find a holomorphic branch of $\log$ on $U$ and exactly use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @Arkady Thank you. Please write an answer as to how can I find a holomorphic branch of $\log$. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Arkady We need to carefully define the logarithm of the zeta function. How do we do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The existence of a branch of log for any holomorphic function not vanishing on a simply connected open set is a result in complex analysis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137034/discussion-between-arkady-and-ava).

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a holomorphic function on a simply connected region $U$ and $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z\in U$, there exists a holomorphic function $g$ such that $\exp \circ g = f$. This is a standard result in complex analysis. See the reference cited [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Logarithms_of_holomorphic_functions).

You have constructured the simply connected region $U$ on which $f(s) = (s-1)\zeta(s)$ is non-vanishing and holomorphic so just apply this result. Then you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to conclude.

Comment: But how do we define the logarithm of the zeta function?

Comment: Have you checked the link? It has a recipe there.

Comment: Yes I checked it. But you have not used the properties of zeta function. My professor is not convinced with the application of FTC here.